# Action / Hook when a new plugin is added

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, actions

Is there an action hook when a new plugin is installed?

I want to hook into the moment when a new plugin was put into the `/wp-content/plugins` folder. So really just adding the plugin (either via upload or via installation through the admin interface to pick plugins for installation).

Please note I am **not referring to the activation** of a plugin ([**`activated_plugin`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/activated_plugin/) does that trick).

Comment: There's no hook for that that I know of. [hookr.io](http://hookr.io/) is pretty useful for browsing all of the hooks at once.

Comment: you would need to check for this on every single request and then fire a hook yourself to catch when someone drops a plugin in that folder via FTP or other means, which could be costly. You'd also need to maintain a list. What's the reason for wanting to do this? What are you trying to do that requires it?

Comment: Is it your plugin that you can code?

Comment: There is a need for a server-side script, nothing to do with WordPress.

Comment: @TomJNowell Adding folders via FTP is out of scope. I am only concerned what WordPress offers via the admin UI. So the package upload and "online install" from the WP.org repo. I had hoped I can get an info for that cases.

Comment: @hbit what are you trying to do that requires this? There's not a lot of context here and what you've asked is not straightforward, it's likely a workaround/hack is necessary which means what you want to do will heavily impact wether this is even possible or not. There are filters, but they do not map cleanly on to a neat single filter. E.g. if you wanted to log this to an audit log you would need a very different answer to if you wanted to modify something, or if you wanted to auto-activate etc etc, you need to provide more information

Comment: @TomJNowell I want to log the event to an audit log.
I guess I am stuck doing it via looking into each request and not get called up by an action hook.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bit tricky but using https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugin_loaded/ to know if the plugin has just been activated.

I think check if a plugin is added to `get_option('active_plugins');`

And doing your stuff when you detect something new

Comment: How does this help to recognize the plugin installation?
Again: not talking about the activation with my question.